# Prove correctness of iterative LCM algorithm

Tags: algorithm-analysis, correctness-proof, loops, loop-invariants

I have been trying to prove the following algorithm, without success.

Here is the C-Style pseudocode:

```
//j,k >= 0
int get_lcm(int j, int k){
    int c = j;
    int d = k;
    while(c != d){
        if(c < d){
            c += j;
        } else {
            d += k;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

I tried to find the loop invariant, which ended up being something like:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&c\le\text{LCM}(j,k) \wedge d\le\text{LCM}(j,k) \wedge c=aj \wedge d =bk\\
&(a,b \in N)
\end{aligned}
$$
I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I understand intuitively why the algorithm works, but I'm having trouble putting out an actual formal proof of it.

I need to come up with an invariant such that $c=d=LCM(j,k)$ when $c=d$. I'm having trouble showing how $c, d \le LCM(j,k)$ after one iteration.

Can anybody please help me? Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can not "prove an algorithm". What exactly are you trying to show? What *is* your intuition about what the algorithm does?

Answer (score 1):

Assume j, k > 0.

You have your loop invariant. Every iteration, one of c or d gets larger. They cannot forever stay ≤ LCM (i, j), therefore the loop must finish.

Because c and d are multiples of i, j, they cannot change directly from being < LCM (i, j) to > LCM (i, j), instead there must be a step for each of c and d where it is equal.

If both are = LCM (i, j) then c = d and the algorithm exits. If one is = LCM (i, j) then the other one is smaller and gets increased.

Comment: How do I show that the loop invariant is true? Each one of c, d gets larger, but how to show that it does not exceed the LCM?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to write it down mathematically but may be I can do good with words to give you an idea.

You should ask yourself the question

**What's the smallest possible LCM of `j` and `k`?**

**Ans-** When the LCM is either `j` or `k`(When one divides the other without remainder).

**So now what's happening in the loop**

**1**. `c` is a multiple of `j` (since it is initialized with the value of `j` and increments by `j` whenever `c` is smaller than `d`).

**2**. Similarly `d` is a multiple of `k`.

**Now let's come to the point**

If `j` is the LCM then As long as `j` is greater than `k` , `d` will continue to increase unless `d` becomes equal to `m*k` where `m` is a factor of `j`.

If `k` is the LCM then As long as `k` is greater than `j` , `c` will continue to increase unless `c` becomes equal to `n*j` where `n` is a factor of `k`.

**Mathematically, LCM can be defined as**

***LCM(j,k)=j*n=k*m*** where `n` and `m` are the times `j` and `k` are added to themselves

**So if an LCM exists then in the loop**

`c`(the iterative multiple of `j`) must become `j*n` before becoming `j*(n+1)`.

Similarly `d`(the iterative multiple of `k`) must become `k*m` before becoming `k*(m+1)`.
which is the same as saying that

**c == d** will be true at some point.